# how to color a word in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I a trying to develop a web based compiler using nodeJS. My goal is to color each syntax. Such as for the following C code:

```
int var;
printf("%d",var);
```

I want to color the "int" and printf here.
I have done following code until today where each letter has turned to red during typing.

```
<textarea rows="13" cols="150" id="code" name="code" placeholder="do ypur code here" onfocus="if(this.value==''){
          this.value='#include<stdio.h>\n' +
  'int main(){\n' +
  'return 0;\n' +
  '}';
  this.style.color='green';
  }"
   onkeyup="keyup()" onkeypress="pre()" onkeydown="down()" >
 function keyup()
  {
    document.getElementById('code').style.color='green';
  }
  function pre()
  {
    document.getElementById('code').style.color='red';
  }
  function down()
  {
    document.getElementById('code').style.color='green';
  }
```

I am looking for advices to put differnt , colors for standard i/o, data types.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could use an existing lib: https://highlightjs.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [colors](https://github.com/Marak/colors.js) package to select color for text and background.

### Install package

```
npm install colors --save
```

### Usage

```
var colors = require('colors');
console.log('hello'.green); // outputs green text
```

OR

```
var colors = require('colors/safe');
console.log(colors.green('hello')); // outputs green text
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It work well on console, but it seems the OP wanted something in browser (`document.getElementById` is HTML)

Comment: thank you all for this advice but i want to change color on my text area for different word. how can i do this?

Comment: DrakaSAN, GaneSH, can you please highlight the issue by informing me how to color the syntax in browser/client side